# Curved line in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9nb6.jpg)

I want to draw a curved line between point A and B in Xamarin
How can I do it?
I have the Point A, B, C

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-shapes-and-paths/

Comment: You need to do more research before post a question, and also need to be more accurate

Answer (score 0):

You can use SkiaSharp [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/)